# Visual Studio express shows error : "internal error occured in compiler"

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, visual-studio-express

I created visual studio files for the c++ library g2o using cmake. But when I try to build it, it is failing showing an error at some template definitions.

```
template<>
inline void axpy(const Eigen::MatrixXd& A, const Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>& x, int xoff, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>& y, int yoff)
{
  y.segment(yoff, A.rows()) += A * x.segment(xoff, A.cols());
}
```

As I am not an expert in c++, I am not sure what is going wrong in this line of code. I tried commenting this code and building. Then the build fails on the next template definition. Is it an issue with visual studio?

The error shown is

[image]

The same code is working perfectly on linux. But I need to run it on my windows machine as debugging is easier and I have only limited access to the linux machine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Visual Studio 2010. Can you upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: @Dani it is Visual studio express 2013..i think the newest version :(

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. Have you tried looking at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback to see if anything looks relevant?

Comment: I've got similar problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I too have this problem.  Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

In windows VS environment, you need to change the template specification.
Change the `template<>` into `template< Eigen::MatrixXd >` will works